# Editing website HTML and intercepting any responses

Tags: html, web, developer-tools

My college has some web software that is absolutely horrific and I want to redesign it locally to save my eyes. Obviously I could use developer tools but that gets overwritten on a reload, but I was wondering if it's possible to edit something in the developer tools (like remove a div) and to then 'save' it as to intercept any response from the server and rewrite it using the HTML I have 'saved'

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Greasemonkey, at least for Firefox and Chrome. Stylish may also work but won't give you the same range of editing options Greasemonkey will.

Comment: @computerfreaker I use something that sounds similar called tampermonkey (beta). Would that do the same?

Comment: Just from glancing at Tampermonkey's docs, it does seem like that would do the same. I've not used it myself though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was a hacky one but it worked. I decided to use TamperMonkey, which injects JavaScript code in the bottom on a HTML page. Using this and JQuery, I just modified the HTML.